# Vampire Class Spellcasting Doesn't Make Sense

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, homebrew

In our campaign my character got infected with vampirism. Our DM has not given me any rules or stats for becoming a vampire so I'm trying to figure it out myself and get his approval. I'm looking at this homebrew vampire class to multiclass into: [Vampire Class](http://www.tribality.com/2015/10/30/dd-5e-vampire-class-and-custom-backgrounds/). But the spellcasting doesn't make sense.

At level 2 you get the Blood Magic (Level 1) Legacy (Feat) which allows you to use 1st level spell slots gained from the vampire class, but you don't get 1st Level Spell Slots until level 3 or even the Spellcasting ability.

As a Vampire you get to choose a bloodline. If you choose the Thaumaturge Bloodline you get a different spellcasting path. You get a spell book with 4 1st level spells, but again you get the "Feat" to cast 1st level spells at level 2 and don't get the spell slots till level 3.

Can anyone shed light on how spellcasting is supposed to work for this class? Explain why it is set up this way? Or offer another vampire class I can use that works better? I chose this one because it seemed like it was the most ironed out.

Comment: Is there a reason you and your GM aren't utilizing the "Player Characters as Vampires" sidebar in the MM? It would seem like the most-obvious way to get "rules or stats for becoming a vampire" that would garner approval.

Comment: The setting of our campaign is the Elder Scrolls universe and it's a part of the story that I remain in control of my character. None of the other character's know that I'm a vampire yet. Plus while I could easily use what's in the MM I wanted a vampire class I could progress in.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Ask the designer.

When it comes to homebrew content, there are often issues with editing, balance, or other parts of class design.  One benefit of using a relatively new homebrew class is that homebrew designers are pretty likely to respond to questions about their class, and possibly even update the text if something is unclear enough.

At the bottom of the article you link, it says:

> Jessica Deuel is a long time fan of table top RPGs. When she isn’t in class or enjoying RPGs with friends, she likes to do constructive things like argue with people on the internet or play Facebook games. You can reach her at vinsklortho@gmail.com

I would suggest emailing her directly, and ask her what she meant.  You're more likely to get a useful answer that way, than asking people who have no experience with the class and don't know her design processes.

Comment: Is this really a *valid* answer? This does sound like good advice, but i dont think any thought was put on the question. This could be answered to any question that has the homebrew tag on it.

Comment: @ShadowKras When the question can be summarized as "this homebrew doesn't make sense, help?", then this is a valid answer. For any other type of homebrew question, this would not work as an answer. The most objectively correct answer is the one that the original author of the homebrew can give.

Answer (score 1):

### You have the option to play without spells.

This is explained on this note from the author:

> There was talk early on about having vampire subclasses that have no spellcasting ability since there are many examples of non-caster vampires in fiction. Instead **I decided to keep spell slots as a resource system for all vampires, but I included a series of legacies that allow vampires to spend spell slots on non-spell abilities**. If you want to play a vampire that never casts a single spell then take a look at the “vampiric” line of legacies. These all offer ways to make use of spell slots in a non-spellcasting manner and none of them are bloodline specific.

This means that, if you dont pick the *Blood Magic* Legacy, you will not be able to cast spells past 1st level. That is, since you gain *Blood Magic* lv1 for free, you can use and cast 1st level spells, but to cast 2nd and higher level spells you need to buy the other levels of Blood Magic aswell (lv2, lv3, and so on).

You can also use your spell slots to use for other abilities of the class, such as *Unholy Smite*:

> When you hit a creature with a weapon attack, a bite attack, or an unarmed strike, **you can expend one vampire spell slot** to deal necrotic damage to the target, in addition to the weapon’s damage. The extra damage is 1d8 for each level of the spell slot to a maximum of 4d8.